# VisualVM and Java 5

Tags: java, profiling

As for this [VisualVM Features](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html) *'VisualVM runs on Oracle/Sun JDK 6, but is able to monitor applications running on JDK 1.4 and higher'*.

What I'm trying to do is monitor JBoss 4.2 applications running under JDK5. I guess I could do something like using a machine running Java 6 and trying to remote monitoring my Java 5 applications but my question is: Is there any way to get VisualVM running under Java 5 Virtual machine?

Comment: Why not download the Java 7 installation from Oracle and run VisualVM on Java 7 whist running your application on Java 5. VisualVM will not run on earlier versions of Java.

Comment: What I would like to do is running VisualVM in Java 5 without having to install any additional Java version

Comment: You can use JConsole.